# What properties are available on a "scroll" event in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

MDN docs at [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event) doesn't show/list any properties available to the "scroll" event object but it does show properties available to "wheel" event [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event). I'm trying to find out, hopefully from the "scroll" event object, what direction the user is scrolling i.e top/down from some sort of property i.e "deltaY". I tried inspecting the "scroll" event object in dev tools of both firefox and chrome and it doesn't seem to suggest any properties on that event object. Maybe I should try to code in an IDE and see if an IDE can suggest/list properties available to the "scroll" event object? Lol, I even resorted to looking at the HTML specs but unless I didn't research thoroughly enough, it doesn't seem to show anything about the properties on the "scroll" event. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Example of how MDN documents properties available on "wheel" event but not the "scroll" event:
[image: mdn docs on wheel event]

Comment: I think you have to implement this yourself. Save the scroll position each time, and compare the current position to the previous.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the suggestion. Lol, do you know what property specifically is used to get the scroll "position"? that's sort of the type of information i'm looking for on this event.

Comment: Note that the scroll event doesn't imply any kind of directional movement. You don't have to drag anything, since you can just click on a spot in the scrollbar and it's an instantaneous movement. That's why it doesn't have a direction like the scroll wheel.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. yeah that makes sense. I initially went with "onWheel" event in react instead of "onScroll" but then that event just bubbled up and caused the whole page to scroll as well so I switched to "onScroll" because react docs does state it doesn't bubble up but now not sure where to go from there. lol, i see the examples used in MDN docs and i want to emulate that behavior but for horizontal scrolling with the mouse wheel in react. but that's a different SO post i'll make if no progress here.

Answer (score 1):

The "scroll" event is a plain generic Event. It has properties like "type", "target", etc, but nothing specifically about what happened to trigger the event (other than the implicit fact that the user scrolled the window somehow).